# VBA Currency to Text Conversion

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of currency values in one WorkSheet such as $4,250.00 that I want to compare to the equivalent text/string; e.g. "$4,250" in another Worksheet. When I convert the currency value to text prior to the InStr comparison, I lose the "$" and "," resulting in "4250" which makes the comparison false. Is there a way to convert the currency value to text and not lose the format?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a very much error-prone way of going about value comparisons. Consider treating numeric values as numeric values - their string representation on a worksheet has nothing to do with the underlying numeric value. e.g. `If CCur(cellValue1) = CCur(cellValue2) Then` will be much more reliable, and not locale-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

A numeric value can be formatted to currency in VBA using `Format(value, "Currency")`, e.g. `Format(Range("A1").Value, "Currency")`.

Also, the `.Text` property will return the formatted string, so `Range("A1").Text` would give you a string of `$4,250.00` if cell A1 contained 4250 and was formatted in a standard currency format.

In Excel itself, I would suggest using a formula such as `=TEXT(A1,"$#,##0.00")`.

Comment: Looks like the Range("A1").Text yield the format I need. Thank you!!

Comment: You may actually be better off formatting it using `Format(Range("A1").Value, "$#,##0")` because, based on your question, `Range("A1").Text` will give `$4,250.00` and that won't appear in the sample string you gave in the comment to cyboashu, but specifically formatting it as "$#,##0" will give `$4,250` which will appear in the sample string.